# myql join query how to access two table data using php

Tags: php, mysqli

> I have two tables. (**class**, **student**)

Tables Structure:

- **class** :
  id, name, roll_number
- **student** :
  id, class_id, sub, mark

---

I need to :

- select **name**,**roll_number** from class
- select **subject**,**mark** from second

---

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'name' => 'Antony',     //(table class name[field])
        'roll_number' => '1052',//(table class roll_number[field])
        'result' => array(
            'English' => 50,    //(table student sub[English] => mark[50])
            'History' => 70,    //(table student sub[History] => mark[70])
            'Economics' => 65,  //(table student sub[Economics] => mark[65])
        )
    )
    [1] => array(
        'name' => 'Mathew',
        'roll_number' => '1053',
        'result' => array(
            'English' => 40, 
            'History' => 56,
            'Economics' => 65
        )
    )
    [2] => array(
        'name' => 'Cherry',
        'roll_number' => '1054',
        'result' => array(
            'English' => 80,
            'History' => 90,
            'Economics' => 95
        )
    )
)
```

How it possible using join query result?

It is better to execute with a single query.

Comment: show your database schema then we take it from there

Comment: table class fields( id, name, roll_number) value( 10, antony, 1052)

table student fields( id, class_id, sub, mark ) value(1, 10, English, 40)
table student fields( id, class_id, sub, mark ) value(2, 10, History, 56)
table student fields( id, class_id, sub, mark ) value(3, 10, Economics, 65)

Comment: show the second table as well

Comment: table student fields( id, class_id, sub, mark ) value(2, 10, History, 56) 
student table is the second table

Answer (score 0):

Select c.name,c.roll_number,s.sub,s.mark 
from class c 
inner join student s on s.class_id=c.id

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.name, c.roll_number, s.sub, s.mark 
FROM class c 
LEFT JOIN student s
ON c.id=s.class_id